# How to add and delete accordion rows (product registration) Version 2

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, product

Please read the new question regarding this matter below the page, title Verison 2:

I would like to add product registration within accordion. When entering the product registration website one accordion should be visible - product details needs to be entered and then it the user would have to press ADD-button to add the product.

When pressing add button a new accordion with product registration should appear and the above accordion should collapse. So I have managed to do so, but when pressing ADD-button on the second accordion-product-registration it won't add a new accordion nor collapse the active accordion.

Furthermore, the accordions should have a delete button to delete the intire accordion if needed and a edit button as well.

My code looks like this bellow (I had help from the "How to add and delete “rows” in an accordion in jQuery 1" stackoverflow question):

HTML (Bootstrap)

```
<div class="panel-group" id="demo">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8"><input class="form-test" data-parent="#demo" data-toggle="collapse" href="#luk" placeholder="Produktnavn"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" data-parent="#demo" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="removeBtn" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="luk" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body rowbg">
                        <div class="row rowbg">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control trin1 col-md-6" placeholder="Indtast Serie-, Stel-, IMEI-, eller Reg-. nr.:">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control test-product col-md-3" placeholder="Mærke">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control test-product col-md-3" placeholder="Model">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control test-product col-md-3" placeholder="Ny pris">
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <div align="right">
                        <button id="add_item" type="button" data-parent="#demo" href="#luk" class="btn-product btn-success">
                        TILF&Oslash;J
                        </button>
                    </div>  
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
    $('.removeBtn').click(function(){
$(this).parent('div').next('div').andSelf().remove();
    });

    $('#add_item').click(function(){
    $('#demo').append('<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><input class="form-test" placeholder="Produktnavn"></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="removeBtn" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div></div></div><div id="luk" class="panel-collapse collapse in"><div class="panel-body rowbg"><div class="row rowbg"><input type="text" class="form-control trin1 col-md-6" placeholder="Indtast Serie-, Stel-, IMEI-, eller Reg-. nr.:"><input type="text" class="form-control test-product col-md-3" placeholder="Mærke"><input type="text" class="form-control test-product col-md-3" placeholder="Model"><input type="text" class="form-control test-product col-md-3" placeholder="Ny pris"></div></div><div align="right"><button id="add_item" data-parent="#demo" href="#luk" type="button" class="btn-product btn-success">TILF&Oslash;J</button></div></div></div>').demo('destroy').demo(); });

    $(document).on('click', '.removeBtn', function(){
    $(this).parent('div').next('div').andSelf().remove();
    return false; });
```

Btw the attribute = TILFØJ = ADD on English. Translated to Danish

VERSION 2:

How can i automatically add a new ID/CLASS to each new product the user adds?? I have problem getting the the information from the other added products in my DATABASE, due to that the accordion only has one ID and when adding a product the same ID appears on all other accordions, which the database cannot seperate.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `data-attribute` are only available on the page load.

If you dynamicly add elements, you have to affect the JS to new element.

*And, like you will have many panels, don't use ID, it just be unique...*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/122478

**JS** :

```
$toAppend = '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><input class="form-test" placeholder="Produktnavn"></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="removeBtn" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div></div></div><div id="luk" class="panel-collapse collapse in"><div class="panel-body rowbg"><div class="row rowbg"><input type="text" class="form-control trin1 col-md-6" placeholder="Indtast Serie-, Stel-, IMEI-, eller Reg-. nr.:"><input type="text" class="form-control test-product col-md-3" placeholder="Mærke"><input type="text" class="form-control test-product col-md-3" placeholder="Model"><input type="text" class="form-control test-product col-md-3" placeholder="Ny pris"></div></div><div align="right"><button id="add_item" data-parent="#demo" href="#luk" type="button" class="add_item btn-product btn-success">TILFØJ</button></div></div></div>';

makeAddable();
makeDelete();


  function makeCollapsable(){
    $('.form-test').unbind('click');
    $('.form-test').on('click', function(){
          $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().next().collapse('toggle');
    });    
  }

  function makeAddable(){
    $('.add_item').unbind('click');
    $('.add_item').on('click', function(){
          $('#demo').append($toAppend);
          makeAddable();
          makeDelete();
          makeCollapsable();
    });
  }      

  function makeDelete(){
       $('.removeBtn').unbind('click');
      $('.removeBtn').on('click', function(){
         $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
       });
  }
```

**HTML** :

```
<div class="panel-group" id="demo">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8"><input class="form-test" data-parent="#demo" data-toggle="collapse" href="#luk" placeholder="Produktnavn"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" data-parent="#demo" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="removeBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="luk" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body rowbg">
                        <div class="row rowbg">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control trin1 col-md-6" placeholder="Indtast Serie-, Stel-, IMEI-, eller Reg-. nr.:">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control test-product col-md-3" placeholder="Mærke">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control test-product col-md-3" placeholder="Model">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control test-product col-md-3" placeholder="Ny pris">
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <div align="right">
                        <button id="add_item" type="button" data-parent="#demo" href="#luk" class="add_item btn-product btn-success">
                        TILFØJ
                        </button>
                    </div>  
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```